# Send newsletters in email to subscribed users using magento

Tags: php, magento

In magento I have:

- created one template which I want to send to subscribed users.
- Added that template in queue.
- set cron job in magento.

I want to send newsletter template automatically to all subscribed users of store when admin added new products or new promotions using magento admin panel. How can I do that?

My Magento Version is 1.9.0.1

Comment: You can use "catalog_product_save_after"  event and check the product is new or not and if new do your stuff.

Comment: @aton1004, thanks for your reply but sorry to say I am very new to magento so I cant understand what you are saying. Can you please explain it in details ?

Answer (score 2):

I was talking about the use of event-observer in magento. This is like a hook with the help of which you can insert your logic or code before or after some event occurs. For example

> catalog_product_save_after

is the event which occurs after product is saved. You can learn more about it [here](http://www.solvingmagento.com/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/).

You have to create a module that observe this event and there you have to implement your logic that is:

1. get the sku of the recently saved product and check it is already present or not(To check either the product is new or not.This should be check because the product can be edited too because while editing and saving also same event is observed), and then you can do rest i.e sending an email newsletter.

My explaination may seem confusing to you because you are new to this check that link and you will have your concept clear.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply wanting to add a link to the product into the newsletter then you can add a new newsletter template, then insert into this template using the cms widget "Catalog Product Link" you can add a link to a product. This is the same as adding a link to a product via a cms page or block.

If you are looking at sending a product list then I would suggest looking into how the widget "Catalog New Products List" works. You could extend this to take a list of product ids that need to be included in your list.